# Is it possible to add insurance cards to Google Pay?

Tags: google-pay

I just received a new insurance card and would like to keep it in Google Pay. It's not a debit card that can be scanned as a method of payment; I would just like to keep digital copies of all of my cards in a single place on my phone. My State Farm app gave me the option of saving a copy of my car insurance to Google Pay, and I'm hoping there's a manual way to do this for other cards.

I've tried using the Add Pass feature, but there doesn't seem to be an option for just uploading an image.

Comment: It would be Google Wallet and not Google pay, but that's what I want to know too.